# Calculating pdf for sum of two random variables

Tags: probability

I have a random process Z(t).This function is defined as equal to A(t)+B. Well, It's clear that to obtain the pdf of Z(t), I need to take the convolution but I am not getting it how in the solution below the person has calculated pdf for A'(t).Why there are two |t| in denominator.

[image]

Comment: If $X$ is a continuous random variable with probability density function $f_X(x)$, then, for $c\neq 0$, so is $cX$ a continuous random variable with probability density function
$$f_{cX}(a)=\frac{1}{|c|}f_X\left(\frac{a}{c}\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question "Why are there two $|t|$ in the denominator?" is likely due to careless reading of the material you posted. There *are* two $t$'s in the denominators but only *one* of them is the absolute value $|t|$.

Suppose that $X$ is a continuous random variable and that $Y = cX$ for some *nonzero*
real number $c$. Then, for $c > 0$,
$$F_Y(y) = P\{Y \leq y\} = P\{cX \leq y\} = P\left\{X \leq \frac{y}{c}\right\} = F_X\left(\frac{y}{c}\right).$$
The chain rule for differentiation thus gives
$$f_Y(y) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}F_Y(y) 
= \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}F_X\left(\frac{y}{c}\right) 
= f_X\left(\frac{y}{c}\right)\times\frac{1}{c} 
= \frac{1}{|c|}f_X\left(\frac{y}{c}\right).$$
For $c < 0$, a similar calculation yields 
$$F_Y(y) = P\left\{X \geq \frac{y}{c}\right\} = 1 - F_X\left(\frac{y}{c}\right)$$
since $X$ is a continuous random variable which leads to
$$f_Y(y)  = -f_X\left(\frac{y}{c}\right)\times\frac{1}{c}
= \frac{1}{|c|}f_X\left(\frac{y}{c}\right).$$

---

Apart from the mathematical derivation above, there is an intuitive
method of arriving at the same answer. Suppose that $c > 0$. 
The value of $Y = cX$ is $c$ times "larger" than the value of $X$,
that is, we have *stretched* (compressed if $0 < c < 1$)
the horizontal axis by a factor of $c$. 
It would seem reasonable to have the value of $f_X(3)$, say, be
the same as the value of $f_Y(3c)$, or, put the other way
around, $f_Y(y) = f_X\left(\frac{y}{c}\right)$, sounds about right, no? 
Well, *not* quite because the function we end up with must be
a *density* with "total area under the curve" equal to $1$.
So if we have stretched the horizontal axis by a factor of $c$,
the *height* of the function must be reduced by the same factor
to keep the area the same. In short, for $c > 0$, the
answer must be
$$f_Y(y)  = \frac{1}{c}f_X\left(\frac{y}{c}\right).$$
I will leave it for you to work out that for $c < 0$,
$f_Y$ is obtained from $f_X$ by stretching the horizontal axis,
compressing the vertical axis, and "flipping over" the function
with respect to the vertical axis.