# Why do I need the derivative in variable substitution for probability density function?

Tags: calculus, probability

If $y = g(x)$ and $f_X(x)$ the probability density function of X

$x = g^{-1}(y);$

Then 
$f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y)) * (g^{-1})'(y)$

Why do I need to multiply by $(g^{-1})'(y)$?

And not simply:
$f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y))$

Comment: The result that you state is **incorrect**; the probability density function of $Y$ is **not** what you claim it is. When you read your book more carefully and find what the result actually should be, the answer is "chain rule".

Comment: @DilipSarwate I got that function from this link:https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/157

Comment: @TiegoCosta If the notes there do indeed say what you claim they do, go and look at another book. Googling for "transformation of random variable" throws up umpteen entries. You are missing a derivative somewhere.

Comment: @DilipSarwate maybe I'm going crazy, but I don't see anything wrong with what he wrote - he is asking why the derivative needs to be there.

Comment: @DilipSarwate [Wikipedia says the same thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Application_in_probability) or do those vertical lines |(g−1)′(y)| mean anything?

Comment: @guy (a) The formula is missing the absolute value signs, and it seems that the OP does not understand their meaning since he asks "or do those vertical lines mean anything?" (b) I was using a different computer and browser when I wrote my comments. There seems to be a problem with the rendering on that one since the "primes" indicating derivative are hardly visible there, bur clearly visible on this one. The answer as to why the derivative needs to be there is, as I said, the chain rule. $$F_Y(y)=P\{Y\le y\}=P\{g(X)\le y\}=P\{X\le g^{-1}(y)\}=F_X(g^{-1}(y)).$$ Now, differentiate w.r.t. y.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I understand the absolute value signs $|-5| = 5$, but how does it work when using functions which values is converted to absolute?

Comment: TiagoCosta I apologize. There seems to be a problem with rendering of MathJax output on one of my computers, and I could not see the "prime" indicating derivative in your question. The absolute value is needed because $g(\cdot)$ might be a monotone _decreasing_ function in which case the equation shown in my response to @guy has $P\{X\ge g^{-1}(y)\}=1-F_X(g^{-1}(y))$ on the right. For a detailed calculation for the case of a _linear_ function, see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/277204/15941) of mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the [link](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/157) from your comment:

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with density $f$ such that $f(x)>0$ for $c_1<x<c_2$. Let $u:(c_1,c_2)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous, increasing function and let $v=u^{-1}$ denote its inverse. Define a new random variable $Y=u(X)$ (which indeed is a random variable, because $u$ is measurable), then the cumulative distribution function of $Y$ is given by
$$
F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)=P(u(X)\leq y)=P(X\leq v(y))=F_X(v(y)),
$$
when $u(c_1)<y<u(c_2)$. Here we have in the third equality used that $u$ is indeed increasing. To obtain the density of $Y$ we must differentiate $F_Y$ once, and because $F_Y=F_X\circ v$ is a composite function, we can apply the [Chain Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Statement_of_the_rule):
$$
f_Y(y)=F_Y'(y)=F_X'(v(y))\cdot v'(y)=f_X(v(y))\cdot v'(y),\quad u(c_1)<y<u(c_2),
$$
and since $v'(y)=(u^{-1})'(y)=\frac{1}{u'(v(y))}$ we can actually write it as
$$
f_Y(y)=f_X(v(y))\frac{1}{u'(v(y))},\quad u(c_1)<y<u(c_2).
$$

Note that we haven't assumed that $u$ is differentiable, but this is implied by the continuity and monotonicity.

Answer (score 3):

Informal outline:

[image]

If $Y=g(X)$  the events "X falls in the red interval" and "Y falls in the blue interval" are equivalent, and hence they have same probability. But those probabilities are approximately $f_X(x) Dx$, $f_Y(y) Dy$, and then, assuming $g(X)$ is smooth and monotone, and the intervals are small,

$$f_Y(y)= \frac{f_X(x)}{Dy/Dx}\approx \frac{f_X(x)}{|g'(x)|}=\frac{f_X(g^{-1}(y))}{|g'(g^{-1}(y))|}$$

Answer (score 2):

The random variable $X$ has probability density $x\mapsto f_X(x)$ if for all $a<b$ the relation
$$P[a<X<b]=\int_a^b f_X(x)\ dx$$
holds.

Given $X$ and a monotone increasing function $g:\ {\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$ one can consider the new random variable $Y:=g(X)$. It's density $y\mapsto f_Y(y)$ is characterized by the condition
$$P[\alpha<Y<\beta]=\int_\alpha^\beta f_Y(y)\ dy\ .\qquad(1)$$
Now $\alpha<Y<\beta$ is equivalent with $g^{-1}(\alpha)<X<g^{-1}(\beta)$. Therefore we also have
$$\eqalign{P[\alpha<Y<\beta] &=P[g^{-1}(\alpha)<X<g^{-1}(\beta)]=\int_{g^{-1}(\alpha)}^{g^{-1}(\beta)} f_X(x)\ dx\cr &=\int_\alpha^\beta f_X\bigl(g^{-1}(y)\bigr) \bigl(g^{-1}\bigr)'(y)\ dy\ .\cr}\qquad(2)$$
As $(1)$ and $(2)$ hold for arbitrary $\alpha<\beta$ it follows that necessarily
$$f_Y(y)\ \equiv\ f_X\bigl(g^{-1}(y)\bigr) \bigl(g^{-1}\bigr)'(y)\ .$$